# How to put all app.use in a separate common file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have multiple app.use in my index/starting point of my app.

i.e

```
app.use(
    if (!req.contextToken && req.contextTokenchecked) {
      req.queryToFirebase = false;    
      req.contextTokenchecked = true;
      req.contextToken   = {}
      }
    next()
) 

app.use(//Do something 2)
```

and so on..

Now, This is sort of makes my code untidy (in index.js) so I thought about creating a separate js file (say `intialize.js`) which will contain all my `app.use`

Till now, I am used to only creating separate routes

```
const express = require('express')
const router = express.Router()
```

and then import it in my index.js

```
app.use('/auth', auth)
```

But this time I don't want my routes in separate file rather all

```
app.use()
```

In one common.js file

Second, I also have a route which loads data from gmail (gmail.js).

```
app.use('/gmail', gmail)
```

currently, In all the routes, I am adding a middleware  `isLoggedIn`manually.  Is it possible to do something so that all the routes inside it my `gmail.js` inherits that middleware

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking. If you write `app.use('/gmail', isLoggedIn , gmail)` then the middleware `isLoggedIn` is called, before the router stored in the variable `gmail`, and the routing to `gmail` will only take place if `next` is called in `isLoggedIn`.

Comment: @t.niese that was what I am asking. There is also a primary question which was to put all app.use in one separate file. Can you please answer that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The middlewares you register are always executed in the order they are registered. So if you have a code like this:

```
app.use((req, res, next) => {
   // middleware A
   next()
})

app.use((req, res, next) => {
   // middleware B
   next()
})

app.use(middlewareC)

app.use('/gmail', gmail)
```

Then you can for sure create one common file for those middlewares before the `app.use('/gmail', gmail)`:

**common.js**

```
let router = express.Router()

router.use((req, res, next) => {
   // middleware A
   next()
})

router.use((req, res, next) => {
   // middleware B
   next()
})

router.use(middlewareC)

module.exports = router
```

**main.js**

```
app.use(require('./common.js'))

app.use('/gmail', gmail)
```

The API for [use](https://expressjs.com/de/4x/api.html#app.use) (or any others of those registering methods) is `([path,] callback [, callback...])`

So you can register as many middlewares as callback as you want, so you can add a `isLoggedIn` in front of the `gmail` router:

```
app.use('/gmail', isLoggedIn, gmail)
```